# What does this mean: items:Array<any>

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

Very new to Angular and Javascript. I have a homework for angular.js class. We have a code hint and need to create a simple form. In the code hint there is:

```
export class AppComponent {
      items:Array<any>
      constructor() {
          this.items = [];
          this.addItems();
      }
```

I dont understand what is " items:Array" part and how it works. 
How do I create a simple form? Whatever I do my app.module.ts does not work if I change a single thing and this was never an issue.

I have:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <h1> First Name: <input [(ngModel)]="items"> </h1>
    <ul *ngFor="let item of items;let i = index">
    <li>{{i}}: {{item.num}} <input type='button' value='delete' (click)=removeItem(item)></li>
    </ul>
  `,
})
```

Comment: That's TypeScript in the first snippet, not JavaScript.

Comment: Oh okay, so by having Array<any> means the type of the array can have any value in it?

Comment: It means an instance of `AppComponent` will have a property `items` which is an array of any type.

Comment: I would recommend you read their doc [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)

Comment: @ellie_k do you mean you need to add multiple forms?

Answer (score 2):

you are not using javascript you are using typescript this time. so everything you write it's get compiled into javascript and then executed.

```
items:Array<any>
```

you are declaring type here, so you are telling typescript that, this items variable is Array type. it means that items variable can only reference to array nothing else

```
items:Array<any>=[]
items:Array<any>=new Array<any>();
```

but if you try to assign something else

```
items:Array<any>=2
```

typescript compiler will throw you and error and tell that it cannot set number type to array type.

```
<any>
```

this is generic type. you are telling compiler, what types will be inserted in this array. "any"  means that, the items you put inside Array can be anything. numbers,string,object,array... so you could initiate it like this

```
items:Array<any>=["Hello",2,{first:"user1",last:"pass1"},[4,6,7]];
```

but instead of "any" if you write something like this

```
items:Array<number>;
```

it means that only numbers can be inside that array, and if you try to add something else
compiler will throw you an error, that cannot put something else in numbers type Array

Comment: Great answer, I would just suggest a small edit as TypeScript has [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), so saying "`<any>` is a generic type" can be a bit confusing.